# While testing package I get: invalid subscript type 'list'

Tags: r, data.table

While testing my package, I get an error:

```
invalid subscript type 'list'
```

I cannot reproduce the error during interactive testing, only while running tests on my package (ie, Ctrl + Shift + T or Ctrl + Alt + F7 in RStudio/Server).

R associates the error with a typical data.table style join.

```
DT <- DT[ODT]
# where DT is a data.table and ODT is another data.table.
```

Comment: A bit more context would help. I don't know what is in `DT` or `0DT`.

Comment: Point taken, updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Your package needs to import the data.table package in the Description file:

```
Imports: data.table
```